# My progress bar doesnot get the update against background worker.It update after thread completed

Tags: c#, directx

I am using background worker for process meantime i need to update progressbar.
I update the progressBar value using backgroundworker.ReportProgress but the values are updated to the user
 after the background thread is completed.But i need to show the progress bar update while backgroundworker is running.

my code is

```
    public bool IsClosed()
    {
      bool profileClosed = false;           
        for (int i = 0; i < originalEntityList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (originalEntityList[i] is Core.DatabaseServices.Point)
                entityList.RemoveAt(i);
        }         
        CoreApp.ModelSpace.customProgressValue = 0;
        CoreApp.ModelSpace.TotalPercentage = OriginalEntityList.Count;          

        if (!CoreApp.ModelSpace.backgrdWorker.IsBusy)
            CoreApp.ModelSpace.backgrdWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 

        CoreApp.ModelSpace.IndicateProgress(true, new EventArgs()); 

        if (!profileClosed)
                UtilitiesLocalization.ShowMessage(UtilitiesLocalization.ProfileNotClosedMessage, UtilitiesLocalization.InvalidProfileTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        return profileClosed;
    }  



     private void backgrdWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!checkProfileInvalid)
        {
            Thread overlapThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckOverlapEntities)); 
            overlapThread.IsBackground = true;
            overlapThread.Start();
            overlapThread.Join();
        }
    }  




    public static bool CheckOverlapEntities()
    {
        OverlapedEntities.Clear();
        OriginalCollection = new List<Entity>(EntityCollection);
        TempCollection = new List<Entity>(EntityCollection);

        List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();
        for (int id = 0; id < TempCollection.Count; id++)
        {
            CoreApp.ModelSpace.backgrdWorker.ReportProgress(id+1);          

            Entity currentEntity = TempCollection[id];
            if (currentEntity is PolyLine3d && (currentEntity as PolyLine3d).IsClosed) continue;

            Thread tempThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(FindOverlapInParallel));
            threadList.Add(tempThread);
            tempThread.Start(currentEntity);

            if (threadList.Count == MaxThread)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < threadList.Count; i++)
                {
                    threadList[i].Join();
                    if (checkProfileInvalid) break;
                }
                threadList = new List<Thread>();
            }           
        }                     
        CoreApp.ModelSpace.backgrdWorker.ReportProgress(100);
        if (OverlapedEntities.Count > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }  




    void backgrdWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {             
            colorProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            colorProgressBar1.PerformStep(); 
           if (e.ProgressPercentage == colorProgressBar1.Maximum)             
                colorProgressBar1.Value = 0;                                     
    }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're calling ReportProgress and the Progress event handler code?

Comment: Which part of your project is using DirectX?

Comment: Hi friends,  My code below

Comment: The code is confusing. How/where is this code related to RunWorkerAsync() and DoWork() ?

Comment: Your code is really a bit confusing. Why do you start another thread in the background worker and call immediately `Join()`? You could do the work on the bg worker thread. Instead of manually managing threads, you could use `Parallel.For`. Reporting a progress of `id + 1` does not seem reasonable, unless you have exactly 100 elements in the collection. Try `100 * id / TempCollection.Count` instead. You don't wait for all threads to complete. You should allow an early return if you just want a `true` / `false` decision.

Comment: Hi Nico Schertler, I have changed my code according your information.But i am using 3.5 framework. parallel.for available only in 4.0. Is there any other way to do this.